# R: Effect size from simple slopes

Tags: r, regression, effect-size

I have calculated simple slopes for a multiple regression using simpleSlope from package pequod(). Is there a way to easily compute an effect size for a single simple slope analysis from the output?

Example:

```
library(pequod)

dat <- data.frame("DV"=rnorm(20,0,1), "PRED"=rnorm(20,0,1),
                  "MOD1"=rnorm(20,0,1), "MOD2"=rnorm(20,0,1))

fit <- lmres(DV~PRED*MOD1*MOD2, dat)

slopes <- simpleSlope(fit, pred="PRED", mod1="MOD1", mod2="MOD2")
```